# Is cast to void* in a glVertexAttribPointer call a legal C++?

Tags: c++, opengl

This is really a question about C++, not OpenGL. I'm following [this](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Hello-Triangle) tutorial on OpenGL (I've just started), and the author uses C++ (not C). My problem is that `glVertexAttribPointer` [takes](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml) an offset parameter as `const void*`. Since this parameter simply tells OpenGL where a given vertex attribute appears for the first time in the array of vertices that was copied with `glBufferData()`, I would expect that it should be of `std::ptrdiff_t` type. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28063307/in-opengl-why-does-glvertexattribpointer-require-the-pointer-argument-to-be-p) post on SO explains the reason why `void*` is used as an argument type, but I wonder why such a usage is legal in C++. For instance, the mentioned [tutorial](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Shaders) simply casts to `void*` the value of the offset in bytes, like in the call below:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3* sizeof(float)));
```

It seems to me that this approach cannot be legal because the [cpprefence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) documentation of `reinterpret_cast` says

> A value of any integral or enumeration type can be converted to a pointer type. A pointer converted to an integer of sufficient size and back to the same pointer type is guaranteed to have its original value, otherwise the resulting pointer cannot be dereferenced safely (the round-trip conversion in the opposite direction is not guaranteed the same pointer may have multiple integer representations)

So, if I understand this correctly, the `std::ptrdiff_t` value of the offset (which seems to be the one that is needed here) can be lost after the cast to `void*`. What do I miss?

Comment: Yes, it is legal C++. What's technically not legal is doing pointer arithmetic on a null pointer, which is what you're forced to do, when using buffer objects, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8283714/what-is-the-result-of-null-int

Comment: @datenwolf, well I'm actually asking about the fact that the round trip conversion int --> ptr --> int can change the value of int, which suggests that it cannot be legal.

Comment: It’s indeed invalid. See also comments on https://stackoverflow.com/q/58679610/1968.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph Thanks, that's exactly what I wanted to know! So the OpenGL API is unfortunate, and not my understanding of reinterpret_cast :)

Comment: @Adrian Yeah, the API is … crap. Even if it were valid (it might be in C, no idea), it’s independently bad because passing a number as `void*` has no benefit.

Comment: @Konrad That was exactly bothering me, thanks again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to cast int to const GLvoid* ?](/questions/23177229/how-to-cast-int-to-const-glvoid)

Comment: @n. 'pronouns' m. I was asking why this is legal (in world with int --> ptr --> int conversion that can change the original int) and not how to make it compile

Comment: The answers to the linked question talk about legality of this too. (It's not really legal)

Comment: @Adrian: "*So the OpenGL API is unfortunate*" Nobody's making you use [bad APIs in OpenGL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37972229/734069).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Not guaranteed " does not mean "guaranteed to fail"; it means "not guaranteed". Which means the implementation may or may not preserve the conversion.

The `glVertexAttribPointer` API requires an implementation of C or C++ that preserves integer->pointer->integer conversions. Much like it requires a C or C++ implementation that offers IEEE-754 floating-point types, as well as 8/16/32-bit integers.

Comment: OK, thanks -- I just wanted to be sure, that it imposes additional requirements on implementation. BTW -- your comment above is also very helpful.